# Div text is going out of DIV

Tags: html, css, asp.net, webforms, bootstrap-4

I have following code for a row and then few text box and buttons inside it.

But the text is going out of the div. Tried overflow attribute but no help.

```
<div class ="row no-gutter">        
        <div class ="col-sm-12" style="margin:8px 0px 0px 0px;padding-left:8px;padding-right:8px;">                         
                <div class ="row">
                    <div class ="col-sm-6" style="margin:8px 0px 0px 0px;padding-left:30px;padding-right:30px;">
                        <div id="MainContent_UpdatePanelCentrifugeSpinAndStep" >                                   
                                            <div class ="row">                                                                                  
                                                <div class ="col-sm-4 text-center" style="margin:2px 0px 0px 0px;padding-right:0px;">
                                                    <div class="form-control input-md" >
                                                        <input id="MainContent_chkLastCycle"  type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$chkLastCycle" />
                                                        End Day Production Re-set
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>                            
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle for same: https://jsfiddle.net/2zfp3g4g/

[image]

Comment: can you share working fiddle/snippet.

Comment: @SuperUser, just posted fiddle link

Comment: you have to share compile code, not asp code, it's not working in fiddle

Comment: @SuperUser, Just posted compiled code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`overflow:hidden` is working. You give overflow property to checkbox parent div.

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                   
<div class ="row no-gutter">        
        <div class ="col-sm-12" style="margin:8px 0px 0px 0px;padding-left:8px;padding-right:8px;">                         
                <div class ="row">
                    <div class ="col-sm-6" style="margin:8px 0px 0px 0px;padding-left:30px;padding-right:30px;">
                        <div id="MainContent_UpdatePanelCentrifugeSpinAndStep" >                                
                                            <div class ="row">                                                                                  
                                                <div class ="col-sm-4 text-center" style="margin:2px 0px 0px 0px;padding-right:0px;">
                                                    <div class="form-control input-md" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;" >
                                                        <input id="MainContent_chkLastCycle"  type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$chkLastCycle" />
                                                        End Day Production Re-set
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>                            
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ankita , but now the text is not showing up properly , https://jsfiddle.net/1dspqdw1/, it's getting cut off

Comment: Many Thanks, How do you find out ? Any resources or books you would suggest?

Comment: Most welcome,  I don't find in any resources or books. I already know that what is an issue because in `form-control` there is given `height:34px`. so i give you `height:auto` and your problem is solve.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the checkbox is in `display: block`. Maybe if you set it to `display: inline` will solve it.